# How do I expand all class="..." attributes to style="..."?

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I'm parsing forum threads with Nokogiri and putting them into a RSS feed. The forum itself doesn't have RSS or any other kind of news feeds.

The problem I've encountered is that elements are styled with CSS classes and via selectors in forums style file included in the page. I can't include it into a news feed, so I want to replace all `class="..."` attributes with `style="<style properties from classes here>"`.

Any ideas how do I do that? Maybe there are some gems able to parse CSS and update Nokogiri parser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to show a sample of what you are parsing, plus a sample of the code you've written.

In addition, RSS doesn't support styles so rather than replace `class="..."` with `style=""` just remove the class info. You can embed HTML in RSS items, but IMO that results in lousy looking feeds and can lead to problems farther down the road if someone else wants to reuse the data. Instead I'd recommend sanitizing the HTML or even stripping all tags.

Comment: html. its not something specific, so example is: xyz{padding: 2px;} <p class="xyz">example</p> - the end. there's no code i've written for this atm, so i didn't add it. if i could don't include any html i would do so.